# Which one is right? (Will or doesn’t)

Tags: questions

Q.the cellphone.....(not work) if it.....(not)have battery

1.the cellphone will not work if it doesn’t have battery

2.the cellphone doesn’t work if it doesn’t have battery

We had to fill the missing words, most of my classmates answered the second answer, the teacher said it was correct, when I told her the first one was actually the correct one she said no we have to use the present simple(or something like that) after that I asked some of the people that are better in English and told me my answer was right

(Just to let you know I’m from Saudi Arabia and some school don’t start teaching English until you become 4th grade but I did learn English earlier since my dad always talk in English)

Answer (score 1):

> Q. the cellphone.....(not work) if it.....(not)have battery

> 1.the cellphone will not work if it doesn’t have battery

> 2.the cellphone doesn’t work if it doesn’t have battery

---

I think two new teachers are in order.

A1

> 1.the cellphone will not work if it doesn’t have battery

**The** cellphone will not work if it doesn’t have **a** battery

---

A2.

> 2.the cellphone doesn’t work if it doesn’t have battery

**The** cellphone doesn’t work if it doesn’t have **a** battery

---

**So the real question is what is the difference between will not and does not**

and the answer is time. **The first answer is correct** because

**it will not work (in the future) if it doesn’t have battery**

and incorrect is

*it doesn’t work (now) if it doesn’t have battery*

correct would be ***it doesn’t work (now) because it doesn’t have battery***